# Build JSON object hierachy from postgres query. Is this correct?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I couldn't figure out, how I can get an hierachical object from a json query.

My sample data is:

```sql
CREATE TABLE
    "postgres"."public"."owner"
    (
        owner_id INTEGER,
        name text,
        mail text
    )
;

insert into owner (owner_id, name, mail) values
  (1, 'Owner1', 'mail@owner1.do.main'),
  (2, 'Owner2', 'mail@owner2.do.main')
;

CREATE TABLE
    "postgres"."public".ip
    (
        owner_id INTEGER,
        status text,
        ip inet,
        host text
    )
;
insert into ip (owner_id, status, ip, host) values
  (1, 'active', '12.34.56.78', 'host78.owner1.do.main'),
  (1, 'active', '12.34.56.79', 'host79.owner1.do.main'),
  (1, 'active', '12.34.56.80', 'host80.owner1.do.main'),
  (1, 'tests failed', '12.34.56.81', 'host81.owner1.do.main'),
  (1, 'tests failed', '12.34.56.82', 'host82.owner1.do.main'),
  (2, 'active', '34.56.78.1', 'host1.owner2.do.main'),
  (2, 'active', '34.56.78.2', 'host2.owner2.do.main'),
  (2, 'not listed', '34.56.78.3', 'host3.owner2.do.main'),
  (2, 'not listed', '34.56.78.4', 'host4.owner2.do.main')
;
```

My intended structure is:

```
{
  "Owner1": {
    "mail": "mail@owner1.do.main",
    "ips": {
      "active": {
        "12.34.56.78": "host78.owner1.do.main",
        "12.34.56.79": "host79.owner1.do.main",
        "12.34.56.80": "host80.owner1.do.main"
      },
      "tests failed": {
        "12.34.56.81": "host81.owner1.do.main",
        "12.34.56.82": "host82.owner1.do.main"
      }
    }
  },
  "Owner2": {
    "mail": "mail@owner2.do.main",
    "ips": {
        "active": {
          "34.56.78.1": "host1.owner2.do.main",
          "34.56.78.2": "host2.owner2.do.main"
        },
        "not listed": {
          "34.56.78.3": "host3.owner2.do.main",
          "34.56.78.4": "host4.owner2.do.main"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

After a lot of trying I came up with this query:

```
select json_object_agg(name, status_ips)
from (
        select name, json_build_object('mail', mail, 'ips', json_object_agg(status, ips)) as status_ips
        from (
                select owner_id, status, json_object_agg(ip, host) as ips
                from ip
                group by owner_id, status
        ) IPS
        join owner
        using (owner_id)
        group by name, mail
) OWNER_IPS;
```

As I have 2 subqueries, my question is: Is this overly complicated? Are there better ways to get my result?

Comment: I probably would have written it [using CTEs](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=edd29f8ebe06deff64fa0671edff8fae) for clarity, but I don't think you can improve the nesting because of the need to do 3 levels of object aggregation.

Comment: Thanks @Laurent Bristiel. I switched in my real application now to CTEs. I hoped for something more straightforward as it is possible, in standard SQL to group by several columns. But it seems to be impossible to use nested json aggregations.